# Use resources item in view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app. I created a resources folder with resources files in it.

In my view I can type:

```
InvoiceStatuses.Received
```

which is the equivalent to "received" so avoiding the magic string.

However in my view I currently have something like:

```
@if (item.Status == "received")
```

I can't seem to use the resource in the view for some reason. I type it but it doesn't recognise it. I guess this is because in the view there is no where to put a:

```
using MyApp.Resources;
```

Can someone please tell me if it is possible to use this resource in the view and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add using to the view use the following syntax

```
@using MyNamespace
```

Once you add the namespace reference you can access any class members that are part of this namespace. 
I believe you can also achieve the same by typing the complete class name and use the shortcut key Ctrl + . to resolve the reference.